# AJAX Record Deletion Using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello i just found a code to delete a row from my database using ajax but the thing is that when the delete is made in the html the table that should dissapear does not work.

here is the js code

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  />
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('a.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
        beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
        },
        success: function() {
            parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                parent.remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});

and the PHP code is this one

```
<? echo "<div class=\"record\" id=\"record-".$id."\" >  
<tr >
    <td><span style='color:#eb8500' >".++$i."</span></td>
    <td width='270px' style='padding:5px'><div align='left' >
     ".$name."
    </div></td>

    <td width='50px' style='padding:5px'><div align='left' >

     <input  onclick='this.select()' type='text' size='15' value='".$link."' />
    </div>
    </td>
    <td style='padding:5px'><div align='center'>
     ".$cat."
    </div>
    </td>
    <td >

    <a  class=\"delete\" href=\"?delete=".$id."\" >Delete</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</div >"; ?>
```

it should delete all the table displayed in the echo, but it doesnt. thank for the help...

Comment: You're problem is that it's not deleting the HTML from the DOM (but it is successfully deleting the record from the database) or vis versa?

Comment: If so, you may want to try `var parent = $(this).parent().parent();`

Comment: thank u that worked pretty well. but now how can i use this function 
 beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
        },
        success: function() {
            parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                parent.remove();
cause after the change for the tr it does not work now.thanks for ur time

Comment: Easiest fix create two different parents i.e. `var parent = $(this).parent();` and `var grandparent = $(this).parent().parent();` and use them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem but if you're trying to remove the `<tr>` when AJAX has successfully completed, then you need to make sure `var parent` refers to the `<tr>` like so:

```
var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
```

[see jquery traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/Traversing/)

Right now, it's going for the immediate parent element to `<a>` which is `<td>`.

Comment: Okay thank you very much , now it works, the tr dissapear, but one last thing please. this function is not working now, how can i make it work now after change to var parent = $(this).parents('tr'); ??? Thanks

beforeSend: function() {
    parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
   },
   success: function() {
    parent.slideUp(300,function() {
     parent.remove();

Comment: what doesn't work? the sliding effect? the bg animation? both?

Comment: the bg animation is the one that is not working, the slide does.

Comment: ah, that's because you can't animate/style on `tr`. Try `parent.children('td').animate({...})`